# Requests module python return only <response 200>, no access to headers

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I have a code with a requests session, and in this session I use:

```
r = requests.session().post(url, data)
```

But then `r` comes out as "response 200" and not as a response object, so doing `r.text` gives out a bunch of gibberish, and `r.headers` just gives ValueError.
How can I get to the Content-Disposition header of that response object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The gibberish returned by `r.text` is the exact content returned by the service at `url`, and `r.headers` must return a dict of the response headers, otherwise you have faulty `requests` module or you don't use it properly.

Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can answer you more clearly

Comment: r = requests.session().post(url, {'data_id': 2, 'data_a': data} and the result of that is that r = <response 200>

Comment: `<response 200>` is not the content of the response, it is a short printable _representation_ of the `r` object (that happens to be your response object).
`r.headers` will return a dict of the response headers